# DataAnnotations namespase error when use CodeTemplates inside the ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, t4

I want change the default code generator of ASP.NET MVC and use [Hanselman Way](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) but there is an error as following picture when add view from controller:

[image]

this is about two namespaces that not in mentioned assemblies: 1-DataAnnotations in System.ComponentModel 2-Linq in System.Data

**Edit:**

Also there is a Warning:

IntelliSense is not available for assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' in the FREE EDITION. Please consider buying PRO EDITION from t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com

I also clear the Custom Tool property for each template.

**How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-Sure using a standard CodeTemplates one of them is here:

C:\Program Files (or x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp (or Visual Basic)\Web\MVC (or 2) 3\CodeTemplates

2-Clear CustomTool Property for each Template.

3-(If not work yet) Restart VS or close all opened Visual Studios and open your project again.

4-(If not work yet) Restart IIS, and maybe need to restart Computer.

5-(If not work yet) Update EntityFramework and restart vs

6-(If not work yet) Open Visual Studio, go to Tools-->Extension Manager in Online Gallery Search and install: **NuGet Package Manager** (if not installed yet) Restart Visual Studio, now open Tools-->Library Package Manager-->Manage NuGet Packages..  in online part: search DataAnnotationExtension or DataAnnotationExtension.MVC3 and install it and restart VS.

7-(If not work yet) I hope work as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is your T4 template missing the following assembly references?

```
<#@ assembly name="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Linq" #>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clsoe Visual Studio
Delete the contents of the Temp folder displayed above C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ in the error message and open Visual Studio or their may be an error in the T4 template.